VScode's microsoft c/c++ IntelliSense can't figure out the offsetof macro
I was coding c++ with clang and I had to use the offsetof macro for something but the C/C++ IntelliSense tell me that there's a identifier "offsetof" is undefined error, even though it compiles and works just fine. I went to its Defination and it took me to __stddef_offsetof.h header file where I see another error squiggles for the __building_module, the error is expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type. now I don't know what any of that means so i asked chat gpt and it says I should consider Updating your IDE and its C++ support packages. but I it already up to date nd stills shows errors. I am on ubuntu please let me know if u know something about this. please do let me know if you wanna know something.
#if !defined(offsetof) ||                                                      \
    (__has_feature(modules) && !__building_module(_Builtin_stddef))
#define offsetof(t, d) __builtin_offsetof(t, d)
#endif


Since it builds, the problem is with your IDE which you don't say which it is.

Unfortunately IntellisSense is less than perfect. Complex or intricate code often defeats it. Personally I just turn it off, that solves any Intellisense problems for me.

@john Intellisense can be perfect. Clangd intellisense never disagrees with clang the compiler, for example.

Your Q here should rather be a bug or feature request filed against the intellisense code.

It is also possible that your c_cpp_properties.json file, the file that specified the intellisense configuration, doesn't specify the correct language standard but tasks.json, the file providing the compiler configuration, does. Remotely Debugging tool configuration problems is always hard. Often figuring out what information you need in the question to make it answerable requires you to first answer the question yourself.
